# Real-valued integral gives large imaginary part

Tags: numerical-integration

I found a very strange result in `Integrate` command. I numerically integrated
$$\int_{-1}^1  \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{|x|^{2/5} |y|^{3/10} |x-y|^{7/10}} dx dy.$$

```
int = 1/(Abs[x]^(2/5) Abs[y]^(3/10) Abs[x - y]^(7/10))
val = Integrate[int, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}] 
N[val]
```

gives the complex answer `17.0597 - 13.2162 I` ! (Before evaluating numerically, the Mathematica gives an analytic expression for `val` as

```
(147 2^(4/5) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[-(3/10)] Gamma[1/5] - 
   210 \[Pi] Gamma[-(3/10)] Gamma[17/10] + 
   210 Sqrt[5] \[Pi] Gamma[-(3/10)] Gamma[17/10] - 
   700 (-2)^(4/5) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/5] Gamma[17/10] - 
   2100 Gamma[-(3/10)] Gamma[17/10] Hypergeometric2F1[1/10, 7/10, 11/
     10, -1] + 
   300 Gamma[-(3/10)] Gamma[17/10] Hypergeometric2F1[7/10, 7/10, 17/
     10, -1] - 
   700 Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]] Gamma[-(3/5)] Gamma[13/10] Gamma[17/10] Root[
    512 + #^10& , 4, 0])/(63 Gamma[-(3/10)] Gamma[17/10])
```

.) Note that the large imaginary part cannot be regarded as the numerical error. This is very strange, since the integral is real-valued. Why this error occurs?

- I am using version 12.1.

Comment: The same issue in 12.3.1 on Windows 10. `RealAbs` instead of `Abs` does not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in higher versions of MMA.

In version  `"8.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (December 9, 2010)"`   you get the right result independent of the order of integration. Although the two soutions look different, they are equivalent.

```
integrand = 1/(Abs[x]^(2/5) Abs[y]^(3/10) Abs[x - y]^(7/10));

int1 = Integrate[integrand, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]

int2 = Integrate[integrand, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]

(*   (49 \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[1/10] Gamma[7/10] Gamma[9/10] - 
49 Sqrt[5] \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[1/10] Gamma[7/10] Gamma[9/10] - 
49 \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[2/5] Gamma[7/10]^2 Gamma[9/10] + 
49 Sqrt[5] \[Pi]^(3/2) Gamma[2/5] Gamma[7/10]^2 Gamma[9/10] + 
70 Sqrt[\[Pi]]
 Gamma[3/10] Gamma[2/5] Gamma[3/5] Gamma[7/10] Gamma[17/10] + 
35 2^(4/5) \[Pi] Gamma[1/5] Gamma[2/5] Gamma[9/10] Gamma[17/10] + 
35 2^(3/10) Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]]
 Gamma[1/5] Gamma[3/10] Gamma[2/5] Gamma[7/10] Gamma[9/10] Gamma[
 17/10] + 
175 2^(4/5) \[Pi] Gamma[2/5] Gamma[9/10] Gamma[6/5] Gamma[17/10] - 
700 Sqrt[\[Pi]]
 Gamma[2/5] Gamma[7/10] Gamma[9/10] Gamma[17/
 10] Hypergeometric2F1[1/10, 7/10, 11/10, -1] + 
100 Sqrt[\[Pi]]
 Gamma[2/5] Gamma[7/10] Gamma[9/10] Gamma[17/
 10] Hypergeometric2F1[7/10, 7/10, 17/10, -1])/(21 Sqrt[\[Pi]]
Gamma[2/5] Gamma[7/10] Gamma[9/10] Gamma[17/10])   *)

int2 // N

(*   35.2503   *)

int1 - int2 // FullSimplify

(*   0   *)
```

**Edit**

May be other versions can do the job, if you get rid of the Abs. Split integration region into 3 parts according to plot of integrand. (Factor 2 due to symmetry)

```
Plot3D[integrand, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 60]

i1 = PowerExpand[integrand, Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1, -1 < y < 0}]

i2 = PowerExpand[integrand, Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1, 0 < y < x}]

i3 = PowerExpand[integrand, Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1, x < y < 1}]

intall = 2 (Integrate[i1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, -1, 0}] + 
 Integrate[i2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}] + 
 Integrate[i3, {x, 0, 1}, {y, x, 1}]) // FullSimplify

(*   10/21 (7 (-1 + Sqrt[5]) \[Pi] - (
7 (-5 + Sqrt[5]) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/5])/(2^(1/5) Gamma[7/10]) - 
70 Hypergeometric2F1[1/10, 7/10, 11/10, -1] + 
10 Hypergeometric2F1[7/10, 7/10, 17/10, -1])   *)

intall // N

(*   35.2503   *)
```

Answer (score 6):

it has to do with the order. If you integrate w.r.t. `x` first, then integrate the result w.r.t `y` then you get positive number.

If you integrate w.r.t. `y` first, then integrate the result w.r.t `x` then you get the imaginary number you showed.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
int = 1/(Abs[x]^(2/5) Abs[y]^(3/10) Abs[x - y]^(7/10));
N@Integrate[int, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N@Integrate[int, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that Mathematica takes the integration variable in reverse order from the order they are listed.

The first one example above integrates over `x` first, then over `y` second, even though `y` appears first.  And the second one integrates over `y` first, then over `x` second, even though `x` appears first. Which is what you had.

Now, why one gives positive real number and the second complex number? I do not know now. This needs more analysis. The Order of integration can make a difference of course (depending on the integrand).

But I do not know why one order gives complex value while the other order does not in this example.

Comment: `NIntegrate[int, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 Exclusions -> {x == y, x == 0, y == 0}, 
 Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo", AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 2]` produces `32.9916` and `NIntegrate[int, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 Exclusions -> {x == y, x == 0, y == 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 3]` results in `35.2476`

Comment: Result of `NIntegrate` doesn't depend on the order of integration:   `NIntegrate[int, {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1},   Exclusions -> {x == y, x == 0, y == 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 3,   PrecisionGoal -> 3]` and `NIntegrate[int, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},   Exclusions -> {x == y, x == 0, y == 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 3,   PrecisionGoal -> 3]` both give the same result `35.2476`

Comment: @Nasser, please see my answer.